# How to list the number of words in a row with the most words?

Tags: python-3.x, text

I try to write the number of words from the longest line. I was able to write the number of words in each line, but I can't print the maximum number. The max () function do not works. Can anyone help me?

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np



with open('demofile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for index, value in enumerate(lines):
        number_of_words = len(value.split())        
        print(number_of_words)
```

demofile.txt

```
<=4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
<=4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
<=4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 sdad adada affg 
<=4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Output:

```
12
10
15
12
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I also don't understand why it lists the number of words in the next lines where there are no words

Comment: The function readlines() returns **all** lines, including empty ones, so when you loop on all the lines, you loop also on the empty lines, which have 0 words.

Comment: Also, you said max() works, what is the problem then?

Comment: Why do you expect the `max()` function to do anything when you never call it?

Comment: You need to record the number of words in each line into a list, _then_ call `max()` on _that new list!_

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly **max()** function doesn't work because you are searching max of strings so you need to convert them to ints(floats).

```
lines = [int(x) for x in lines.split(" ")] // converts to ints
maximum = max(lines)// should work now
```

UPD:
Edited with comment below.
Before:

```
int(x) for x in lines
```

Now:

```
int(x) for x in lines.split(" ")
```

Comment: `int(x) for x in lines` isn't going to work because `lines` is not a list of stringified ints.